# Clearing White lines on the top page, CSS, HTML

Tags: html, css

this problem have been driving me crazy. it always happen.
I have only listed down the important codes.

Below is my HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title> File Manager </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../main.css">     
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="sidemenu">
            <ul>
                <li><a onclick="">Add New Staff</a></li>
                <li><a onclick="">Set Time Limit</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <table class="container";>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Username</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Time</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>    
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS Code:

```
body, html {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}

div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, caption {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}

#sidemenu {
    background: #333;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width:192px;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}
#sidemenu li {
    font: 67.5% "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Bitstream Vera Sans", "Trebuchet Unicode MS", "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
#sidemenu a {
    background: #333;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #393939;
    color: #ccc;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: normal;
}
#sidemenu a:hover {
    background: #2580a2;
    color: #fff;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
}
```

The problem that I have found out using inspect element in Mozila. As you see there are two break lines right below the body. But that code was not in my html code. How do i remove it?

[image]

Comment: Why have you tagged javascript and jquery?

Comment: this is clearly a backend issue ... you php file is generated with these br so check well you php file and find how these br are added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply use this code for your development

```css
body > br {
  display : none;
}
.hello{
  display : initial;
}
```

```html
<br>
<br>
<p>this is your content</p>

<br class="hello">
<p>this is where you like to use br tag</p>
```

Comment: @IvanSim make sure to select the best answer.

Comment: @IvanSim for me this is not a solution, you need to find the real issue and see where and when these br are added and not use a hacky CSS to remove them. And what if you have 100 br in this page ? and what if this CSS is used in other pages ? you are going to manually add hello class to each br you need to keep ?

Comment: OK. i have tried looking through my php codes that i include in the header. But it did not echo any br in the codes.

Comment: Ops found it. it is well hidden in one of the php codes included in the php codes

Answer (score 1):

This is a long shot but try loading [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

Comment: havent tried that, but will look into it. Thanks mate